# Retrofit 2.0 cannot login with post request

Tags: android, post, kotlin, retrofit2

I'm trying to use Retrofit 2.0 to login into a website. This is my first time with Retrofit.
However with the postman and from the website I can do the login with success. This is the request in chrome:[image]

And that is my code:

APIService:

```
interface APIService {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/account/")
    fun login(@Field ("login-ident") username:String,
              @Field ("login-pwd") password:String): Call<String>

}
```

MainActivty:

```
    fun login(username:String, password:String) {
    mAPIService?.login(username, password)?.enqueue(object : Callback<String> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<String>, response: Response<String>) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                showResponse(response.body().toString())
                Log.e("Tag", "post submitted to API.")
            }
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<String>, t: Throwable) {
            Log.e("Tag", "Unable to submit post to API. - "+t.message)
        }
    })
}

fun showResponse(response: String) {
    Log.e("Tag", response)
}
```

Basically, when I run my request what I get in my response body is the login page, while with chrome or postman I retrieve the user page (and that is what I want). What I'm doing wrong? Thanks :D

UPDATE:

This is the generated code of postman (and it works, but my retrofit request doesn't works):

```
    POST /account/ HTTP/1.1
Host: www.placeoldersite.it
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: postman token

------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="login-ident"

myusername
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="login-pwd"

mypassword
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
```

UPDATE 2:

I make a small python script and it works but my retrofit request doesn't works D:

```
    import requests
url = "https://www.myplaceholder.it/account/"
data = {"login-ident":"username", "login-pwd":"password"}

r = requests.post(url, data=data)

print(r.content)
```

UPDATE 3:

I think that the problem is that in my code Retrofit doesn't handle cookies (in this case one cookie), and i can't perform login

Comment: What is the response you are getting?
To be sure, Recheck this if you calling it from same baseURL and also. Also what is the exact error. Also check that if the Model Class should be there or String should be there.

Comment: The server doesn't give me error, if login works than in my body response i will get the html of logged page, but if login failed i will get login page but without error (always 200)

Comment: If by login failed you mean invalid credentials then 200 is ok. Because the server acknowledged the request and answered it. But it should give you a message like successfull: "false"

Comment: but my credentials are correct, because with chrome and postman i can do the login

Comment: If you also created the server can you post code from there also? the route or something

Comment: Do you get any errors in the log? if so please post the errors also as @JSharma suggested remove the `/` but from the beginning not at the end `account/` not `/account`

Comment: Nope, it's not my server, i don't have any sort of code of that. But it works. With chrome i can do the login and also with postman, ican't understand why retrofit doesn't works, i think that the problem is a bad request, but i don't know to make the same request that chrome and postman do

Comment: @HawkPriest No errors, only the login page instead of logged in page. i tried every combinations but same result.

Comment: That's a tough one when you have no errors. My best bet would be to place a debug point on the `response.isSuccessful()` and see if that's getting triggered to true and place a point inside `onFailure()`  and see if that gets triggered. If both don't get triggered, chances are that your retrofit instance is not configured correctly

Comment: response.isSuccessful is true and onfailure isn't triggered. Ps: updated the main post

Comment: small update: if i enter a wrong username or password in response body i will get a html with same login page but with a div and a message that say "id or password are incorrect". So the site recieve my credentials, but i don't understand why, with retrofit if i put my correct credentials then it will answer with login html instead of logged in page html

Comment: I think that the problem is that in my code Retrofit doesn't handle cookies (in this case one cookie), and i can't perform login

Answer (score 0):

Retrofit adds '/' in the path on its own.
try with @POST("account")

Answer (score 0):

Please remove / from @POST("/account/")<- then try

```
@FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/account")
    fun login(@Field ("login-ident") username:String,
              @Field ("login-pwd") password:String): Call<String>
```

I hope it will work you. :)

Comment: can you show your api in post man. so that we can reach at absolute solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to wrap the code within an object which is also easier to handle and then use a converter adapter like `GSON` or `Moshi` to convert the response For instance:

```
data class LoginModel(@SerializedName("login-ident") val userName: String,
                      @SerializedName("login-pwd") val password: String)
```

and pass this to the login function as `@Body` parameter and your service. If the `LoginModel` is to be encapsulated within a `data` object in the json, then you can create a wrapper class else the declaration can be:

```
interface LoginService {
    @POST("account")
    fun login(@Body loginModel: LoginModel): Call<String>
}
```

and then this would work better with the retrofit call. Also make sure that you are getting a string as a response from the server if it's a `JSONObject` I again recommend to use a wrapper `data class LoginResponseModel` and define the json structure as an object that could be parsed by `GSON` or `Moshi`. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hello @JSharma i think this solution will help you. just changes your response model class instead of Call<String> to Call<YourResponseModel> in LoginService Interface.